# How to setup groups (sub-sites) in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I'm new to Django and I come from Drupal family. There we have [Organic Groups](http://drupal.org/project/og) with which we can create groups of content and subsites; how do I do something like that with Django?

Say I'm making this site for my company using Django and every department in my company needs a private section on the site. For example, the design people have their own part of the website into which the back-end developers can not come in. And the back-end developers will have the same thing too.

I want to build the site in such a way that I just login into Django admin and add a new category or subsite or group (whatever the Django term is) with the same settings from other groups or with similar settings.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by "private section". You should probably try looking at it from a different angle:

Django splits a site's *functionality* by means of "apps". Each app does its specific thing, and gets a set of tables in the database. Apps can access each others' tables. For example, it's common for other apps to access the Auth app's user, group, and permissions tables. Is this what you mean by "sub sites"?

As for access control, users can be assigned to groups and they can have various [administrative permissions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#permissions) assigned to them. Add, change, and delete permissions are automatically generated for each model (i.e. database table). You can also add your own permissions.

I don't think you'll be able to separate the designers from the back-end developers at the Django level. You'll need to do something else, such as maintain separate source repositories for each and merge them to create the usable site (each group would have read-only access to the other). It really depends on your teams' discipline, because these elements can get intertwined.

Django recommends that static files be served by something else, say directly from your web server, or from another machine with a simple HTTP server (no CGI/WSGI/whatever). This is because Django can only slow down static files compared to direct service. However, for testing, ther is a static page server you can enable.

Given all that, static files usually amount to CSS, images, media, and JavaScript. Of these, the back-end people *might* want to mess with the JS, but that's it, so this could be in the designers' repo.

The Django tree itself has the code for the site and the apps. It's almost all back end stuff. The exception is the HTML template files, located in the "templates" directory in each app. These are the files that are filled in with the context data supplied by the back-end view code. I have no idea if this is front or back end for you guys; it could be mostly back end if there's a lot of CSS discipline, but I think that's unlikely.

There are a lot of things that you can do in Django that make life easier for one side or the other. For example, template tags allow custom Python code to generate HTML to insert into the page. I use these to generate tab bars and panes, for example.

I really can't help much more without getting a better picture of what your needs are. The question is still vague. You're probably best off taking a day or two going through the tutorial, seeing what the Django perspective is, and then working out how (or if!) it fits into your needs.